# Increase command prompt's buffer size with a command

Tags: windows, command-line

I can change the size of a Command Prompt window like this:

```
'mode con:cols=920 lines=40'
```

But how can I keep the window the same size but increase the buffer size (make the scoll bars smaller, if you follow me) **from the command line?**

I'm running Windows 7, but I would like a command that works in all Windows versions. It's a simple operation, so I think we're okay.

Answer (score 1):

The `mode` command does not (directly) alter the size of the window, it alters the size of the buffer. If you set the numbers to something larger than the window size and it will create scrollbars as necessary. Setting it to numbers smaller than the window will remove the scrollbars and the window will shrink.

There is [a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692673/how-to-change-screen-buffer-size-in-dos-command-prompt-from-batch-script) that gives some more solutions for finer-grained control via the registry or programming if you are interested.

Comment: What can I say, it's definitely enlarging the Command Prompt window! Oh well, it's working okay

Comment: Like I said, it’ll adjust the window size to the buffer as necessary. It does the same thing when you modify the buffer size via the *Properties* dialog. What you need to do is to change the buffer size, then **reset** the window size to what it was. There are no commands that can alter the window size, so you need to use one of the tricks in the SO page. You can use a registry hack, a third-party tool (e.g., [conutils](http://ss64.net/westlake/nt/index.html)), or compile your own program (e.g., [VB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4694566/119540), [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13363943/119540)).

Answer (score 1):

`MODE CON:` lists the buffer size, but not the window size.

`MODE CON: cols=N1 lines=N2` set both both the window and buffer to the same dimensions.

You want to increase the buffer size without changing the window size.

The StackOverflow answer to [CMD: Set buffer height independently of window height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13351373/1012053) shows how to set the buffer and window sizes independently via PowerShell.

A slight modification will set the buffer size without changing the window size:

```
@echo off
:conBufferSize  bufWidth  bufHeight
powershell -command "&{$H=get-host;$W=$H.ui.rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$B.width=%1;$B.height=%2;$W.buffersize=$B;}"
```

Note that the buffer size must be larger than the current window size.

---

**UPDATE**

Below is a modified version that checks the current window width and height and sets the buffer dimension to the window dimension if the provided buffer dimension is too small.

```
@echo off
:conBufferSize  bufWidth  bufHeight
powershell -command "&{$H=get-host;$W=$H.ui.rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$S=$W.windowsize;$B.width=if (%1 -gt $S.width) {%1} else {$S.width};$B.height=if (%2 -gt $S.height) {%2} else {$S.height};$W.buffersize=$B;}"
```

Comment: That changes the window size.

Comment: @Synetech - I don't see how my code can ever change the window size, given that it doesn't access those attributes. I've tested the above, and it works perfectly for me. It changes the buffer size and leaves the window size as is.

Comment: Exactly, as I said in the last line of the answer - the selected buffer size must be larger than (actually greater than or equal to) the window size. It works without error with properly sized buffer. Additional PowerShell code can be used to get the current window size and adjust the buffer size to match if the selected buffer size is too small.

Comment: It’s probably easier to just use a third-party tool or compiled program. That way it can get the current window size and handle everything. I’m half tempted to throw one together. `:-/`

Comment: @Synetech - I added another version that checks the size and compensates as appropriate.

Comment: Nice (albeit obfuscated). Personally, I don’t care for PowerShell, so I prefer a third-party tool. I’ll leave it to the OP to decide what works best for them.